# Prevent load images from the site if the visitor has a mobile device... Opinions?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, user-agent

I'm using media queries, but unfortunately they are inferior to a simple "monolithic" version of the site specifically for mobile devices in the determination of user agents (like Google, Facebook and other sites).
I do not want to do a special version, because I have translated the entire site to media queries. The bottom line is that this method does not have the flexibility in terms of weight loading pages that are critical for owners of mobile phones (in our country the mobile Internet is still very at a high price + images reduce performance). I have matured the idea to use Javascript, which will prevent the browser to load the image at a certain rule (eg screen resolution).
What do you think - is actually realized, and may already have implemented? I know that the site is visited by a lot of smart people and I would really like to hear from you invaluable experience in this area!

Sorry for bad English.

**UPDATE:**
[Prevent images from loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading)

Comment: why deleting?, preventing would be much better

Comment: Yes! Many thanks for the correction. I actually meant it

Comment: I'm not certain, but I'm guessing this will be difficult. Once the `img` tag is in the DOM, it's going to trigger the image load; removing it after this point won't accomplish much in terms of improving load times, and removing it beforehand would be difficult, perhaps impossible, with Javascript.

Comment: I do not want to delete all the images, and probably more, those who are in some html classes ... (although I do not believe in it). What is the same, apparently you're right and it is better to implement it by means of a server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent images from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible solutions to this question. I'll list the common three below.

A CSS only solution, a javascript solution, and a HTML5 solution if you don't care about older browsers:

### CSS

I would suggest moving the images into style tags and use media queries to show the appropriate image:

```
<style>
/* mobile first */
.img {
    display:none;
}

/* tablet */
@media (min-width:600px) {
    .img {
        background:url('/path/to/image-tablet.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    }
}

/* desktop */
@media (min-width:1280px) {
    .img {
        background:url('/path/to/image-large.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="img"></div>
```

Assuming this is a dynamic webpage, you would include the css in the page withing `style` tags instead of in a css file.

### HTML5

If you are not bothered about complete browser coverage ([canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture)), you could also use the new HTML5 `picture` element:

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 1280px)"
    srcset="/path/to/image-large.png">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 600px)"
    srcset="/path/to/image-tablet.png">
  <img src="/path/to/image-mobile.png" /> <!-- a 1x1 empty pixel -->
</picture>
```

In this example, mobile browsers and browsers that do not support it will load the `img` tag. Other browsers will load the appropriate image for the media query.

If you like this solution but also want it to work on older browsers, there are JS scripts you can find that will implement the feature if the browser does not support it.

### Javascript

This approach feels the most hacky to me, but that is just my opinion. It has a very large browser coverage, with IE supporting this method since 10.

Create an image tag without the `src` attribute, and the image size versions as `data` attributes:

```
<img data-tablet="/path/to/tablet.png" data-desktop="/path/to/large.png" />

<script>
var $el = jQuery('img');
if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
    $el.attr('src', $el.data('tablet'));
}
if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1280px)").matches) {
    $el.attr('src', $el.data('desktop'));
}
</script>
```

I've used jQuery to demonstrate, but the important part of this is the `window.matchMedia`. This does a media-query like check and returns a boolean value.