# block image network requests with javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm looking for a reliable way to block image network requests with javascript. I read this: [Prevent images from loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading)

It seems that it's a bit hit-and-miss as to whether the image request or the javascript will fire first.

Does anybody understand the order in which stuff happens? Can I tie into some sort of hook where I can run some javascript before any network requests are made? Or at least abort any existing ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are loaded when the `src` attribute is set. You can either dynamically create the image tags, or just set the `src` attribute when you want the image to load.

Also note that different browsers render pages in different ways. so preventing the load with javascript, is likely to work on certain browsers and not others

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid that - your browser will always try to load the images of your `img` tags. You will have to load the images dynamically via JavaScript.

Comment: You mean that I have to exclude img tags from my markup, and insert them as new dom elements with javascript?

Comment: You'll have to avoid writing img tags into your markup. Create them dynamically. If you'd like to have the image urls inside your markup instead of your JS, you could also use divs with data-url attributes and replace the divs with img tags when you want the images to load.

Comment: OK. That sounds reasonable, but of course won't let me do any progressive enhancement - i.e. I can't support non-js users. Also, I was hoping to block network requests for images from css and indeed other js calls. In short, I was hoping that I would be able to monitor a network request event using js.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to track how many images have been loaded on your page?

Comment: No, I'm hoping to allow the user to manually trigger the download, and potentially for them to indicate whether they want the low or high res version. But I was hoping to do it progressively as this is likely only something that will be relevant on mobile particularly.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with only CSS :) Which browser does not support Javascript these days? ;)

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I was hoping that this could be a nice js only plugin, but it looks like I'll need to modify markup too then. Do you know if it's possible to stop any http requests that are taking a long time? For example, can I interrupt an image load which is taking too long and present the user with some alternate options instead?