# Don't load images within hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is **not a duplicate** of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading) because it also uses the `document.ready` approach which obviously does not work.

I want to avoid that the browser loads images (`<img>`) nested within hidden `<div>` elements.

So I tried this, however the javascript gets executed too late, the browser already starts to download images that it shouldn't.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').not(":visible").each(function () {
       $(this).find('img').each(function() {
         $(this).attr("src","");
       });
    });
  });
```

Is there a good javascript solution for this?
Or do I have to use `<img srctmp="...."/>` and then replace `srctmp` by `src` via javascript for those images which are NOT nested within a hidden `<div>`?

Comment: I believe setting the `src` attribute to `""` doesnt impact this. Try to remove the attribute whole after saving it to `data-src` or something?

Comment: It’s impossible to _stop_ image sources from being downloaded via JavaScript. You’ll have to leave the `src` attribute empty and then insert it later it with another attribute, but use `data-srctmp` instead.

Comment: The code inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});` will always get executed after the DOM is ready (meaning after all the images and content has been loaded). So don't use `ready`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent images from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading)

Comment: @AbraarArique But without `ready` you can’t access any element. When images finish loading the `load` event is dispatched, not `DOMContentLoaded` (`ready`).

Comment: How else do you want to access your `<img>` elements before loading, if not with `document.ready`? This is impossible; therefore the duplicate flag is still valid (even solely for the reason that the answers will be identical).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `data` attribute instead the `src`, browser loads images only form `src`, so you can start with `data-src` for every images and then add the `src` only to the visible ones.

HTML:

```
  <img data-src="path/to/image.jpg" />
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').is(":visible").each(function () {
       $(this).find('img').each(function() {
         $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
       });
    });
  });
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I will try it out and select it as solution if it works. Thanks for your time.