# JS: Prevent images loading lazy after setting to display:block

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

On my website I need to toggle the visibility of complete articles.

When I make them visible (`display:block`), the text appears very fast while the space, where the image should be, is white. After a half or a second the image appears from once (it was loaded from the server before, so that's not the prob xD).

Now maybe there is a solution where I can hold the image in the RAM.

I don't even know how to call the Problem so I couldn't found much on google.

(Its important to take the article out of the `DOM-Tree` so setting opacity or visibility to 0 is not a solution).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: probably the title, just missing a "how to"

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the browser how it stores and fetches images from cache. There are a lot of factors, including what else the browser is doing, how many images, how big they are, etc. If it's taking that long, it's possible they are getting forced out of cache or they are too big or some other problem. Have you checked to make sure they are indeed being cached (again, this may be somewhat browser dependent)? Also make sure you don't have caching disabled (in your dev console or similar).

There are a lot of potential options to manage the image data, really depends on what you are doing as to the best solution.

Comment: Thank you that actually helped me a bit, since i dont know anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1667886/888278) explains it clearly. In short,

> If you render the HTML on the page, even if it's hidden, it's going to
>   load. If you want images to load only when they're needed, you're
>   going to have to dynamically set the source (src) on the image tag in
>   javascript.

Comment: thats not my problem. The image is already loaded from the server. Then i hide it with display: none. Then i show it again with display: block. Then its lazy. (Probably because it is not any more in the RAM)

Comment: Sounds like you either have some wierd cache control headers on your response. Or you are simply not waiting for the image to load completely before you remove it from the DOM (This will cause the fetching of the image to abort on most browsers)