# DOM img node with src without loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using jQuery on DOM elements that are not added to the DOM tree of the actual page, nor will be, to render some HTML and get it as a string.

Minimal example is simply evaluating:

```
$('<div><img src="foo.png"></div>').html()
```

Unfortunately, this causes the browser to try to load the image.

How can I prevent this?

This is in the context of a Chrome app, so a chrome-specific solution is acceptable.

In my use case, simply avoiding the DOM elements is not an option: In the actual code, the existing templating machinery uses DOM elements and jQuery to assemble the output. Similarly, I cannot simply replace `src` with `data-src`.

Comment: Where is this markup coming from?  You say there's a template but how does it get applied?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent images from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667868/prevent-images-from-loading)

Comment: any reason you don't want it to load the image? do you never want to load it, or do you want to tell it when it must load?

Comment: @darryn.ten, I am creating a static copy of (parts) of the web app output, for archival purposes. So the browser never gets to see it. Also, the URLs are not valid anyways.

Comment: so then why not output it as an escaped/quoted string instead of as a valid dom element?

Comment: Because the templating system works internally with DOM elements, not strings.

Comment: Best shot so far is http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863227/946226 but I cannot get it to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMParser

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString('<div><img src="foo4.png"></div>', 'text/html');
```

The html is in `doc.body.innerHTML` if you need to do something with it

Comment: or just a DocumentFragment

Comment: This does not work for me, as the tempting code insists on using jQuery to assemble the different pieces of the output.

Comment: I didn't but it sounds like a perfect fit : create DOM structure which is not part of the main DOM. I can't test it r-n so is there any issue ?

Comment: @Kaiido - I admit I thought so too, but no matter how I tried adding the HTML to a fragment, it would try to load the image

Comment: @JoachimBreitner - I see the problem, perhaps if you showed some more relevant code I could see if there's something that could be done

Comment: Ah weird... (the only way I thought was with innerHtml, since yes all imageElement created from the document will load...) should have tested before commenting.

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping for some trick like http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863227/946226 to work. But if the answer is “no, does not work”, feel free to post that as a proper answer.

Comment: I tried using <!--StartFragment--><!--EndFragment--> But the result was the same.

Comment: @Stiffels - what does two HTML comments have to do with this 4 and a half year old answer?

Comment: @JaromandaX - It is one of the ways to try to avoid loading the tag by adding the Fragment option to it. This comment-out syntax is generated by the browser when you make a clipboard copy of a selection in the browser.

Comment: @Stiffels - if you have an answer, please post one, don't confuse me with comments about comments that make no sense to me :p